# polynomial with integer coefficients 7

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients and $a$ and $b$ are two integers and $f(b)-f(a) = 1,$

then prove that $|b-a| = 1$

assuming $f(x)=a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot +a_{n}x^n$ and $a_{0},a_{1},a_{2},.......,a_{n}$ are integers

put into $f(b)-f(a) = 1$

$a_{1}(b-a)+a_{2}(b^2-a^2)+\cdot\cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot+a_{n}(b^{n}-a^{n}) = 1$

i want to go further, could some help me with this

Comment: What is the significance of the "7"?

Comment: because polynomial with integer coefficients 1,2,3,4,5,6 all are exists , it is just numbering

Comment: **Hint**. $g(x) = f(a+x)-f(a)$ is also a polynomial with integer coefficients, $g(0)=0$, and $g(b-a)=1$.

Comment: x @DURGESH: The existence of other questions with similar titles ought to be a hint to you that **you have chosen a lousy title for your question**, and you ought to come up with a more descriptive one rather than simply thumb your nose at the software feature that honestly tries to discourage you from using lousy titles.

Comment: OK Henning Mekholm, i will take care in future.

Comment: Use one `\cdots` instead of lots of `\cdot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. In
$$
a_{1}(b-a)+a_{2}(b^2-a^2)+\cdots+a_{n}(b^{n}-a^{n}) = 1
$$
note that $b-a$ is a factor of all terms $b^k-a^k$ and so
$$
(b-a)c = 1
$$
for some integer $c$.